# Crispy forms CheckboxSelectMultiple display inline

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I am having a lot of difficulty getting a MultipleChoiceField list to display inline using crispy. I have tried adding div's between by displaying the form using

```
{{ for field in form }}
```

but it places the div's between each selectbox AND the select boxes label.

This is where I create the CheckboxSelectMultiple:

```
preferred_topics = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=TOPICS, required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

And I am printing it out with:

```
{{  form|crispy }}
```

I also have many other form types before and after this field (text boxes etc)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use the [{% crispy %} tags](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#crispy-tag-with-forms) and `FormHelper`. This will allow you to use [`InlineField`](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html?highlight=inline#bootstrap3-inline-forms).

There is also the [table option](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_formsets.html?highlight=formset#custom-templates-and-table-inline-formsets) which doesn't use `divs`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll give it a try